# Property gamma for type III factors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am struggling to find a definition which uses centralizing sequences for property gamma in type III factors?
If $M$ is type $\mathrm{III}$ factor, what is the exact definition of property gamma without using the equivalent  definition: the relative commutant of ultrafilter of $M$ in $M$ is nontrivial?

Comment: Property $\Gamma$ and fullness are opposites over type $\mathrm{II}_1$ factors. You would have a better time googling for full type $\mathrm{III}$ factors, like: https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.09613.